# second for loop only loop one time in every first loop

Tags: angular

`*ngFor` in a `*ngFor` but I want the second loop only loop one time in every first loop.

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Ad Soyad</th>
        <th>Ödev</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let ogrenci of ogrenciler">
            <tr *ngFor="let odev of odevler">
                <td>{{ ogrenci.Adsoyad }}</td>
                <td>{{ odev.Odev }}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXGeR.png)

Comment: Do you mean this https://angular-ivy-fezeyo.stackblitz.io ?

Comment: What do you mean by "loop only one time in every first loop"? Can you provide some example data and expected output?

Comment: i have two list, and i'm trying to match second one to first one

Comment: Still not making any sense ... Especially without example data

Comment: In the code listed, the inner `*ngFor` will run once for every item in the outer loop. That’s how loops work. If you only want it to loop under a condition, use conditional logic `*ngIf` and the like.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.